# Simulate Lag Function - Spark structured streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark Structured Streaming to analyze sensor data and need to perform calculations based on a sensors previous timestamp. My incoming data stream has three columns: sensor_id, timestamp, and temp. I need to add a fourth column that is that sensors previous timestamp so that I can then calculate the time between data points for each sensor.

This is easy using traditional batch processing using a lag function and grouping by sensor_id. What is the best way to approach this in a streaming situation?

So for example if my streaming dataframe looked like this:

```
+----------+-----------+------+
| SensorId | Timestamp | Temp |
+----------+-----------+------+
|     1800 |        34 |   23 |
|      500 |        36 |   54 |
|     1800 |        45 |   23 |
|      500 |        60 |   54 |
|     1800 |        78 |   23 |
+----------+-----------+------+
```

I would like something like this:

```
+----------+-----------+------+---------+
| SensorId | Timestamp | Temp | Prev_ts |
+----------+-----------+------+---------+
|     1800 |        34 |   23 |      21 |
|      500 |        36 |   54 |      27 |
|     1800 |        45 |   23 |      34 |
|      500 |        60 |   54 |      36 |
|     1800 |        78 |   23 |      45 |
+----------+-----------+------+---------+
```

If I try

```
test = filteredData.withColumn("prev_ts", lag("ts").over(Window.partitionBy("sensor_id").orderBy("ts")))
```

I get an `AnalysisException: 'Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets`

Could I save the previous timestamp of each sensor in a data structure that I could reference and then update with each new timestamp?

Comment: I took the GroupState suggestion and have been working off of [this blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/17/arbitrary-stateful-processing-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html) but have yet to get anything working in a databricks notebook.. Please let me know if you figure something out!

Comment: Hi Matt...Did you get the solution for this problem?

Comment: Hey did you guys figured this out, how to solve this problem ?

Comment: By storing in data structure, are you referring to storing the data in memory for query. Then yes you can create a temp view in spark and then join for last updated time. But this table will stay only for the lifetime of your code running and will take up memory

Answer (score -7):

There is no need to "simulate" anything. Standard window functions can be used with Structured Streaming.

```
s = spark.readStream.
   ...
   load()

s.withColumn("prev_ts", lag("Temp").over(
  Window.partitionBy("SensorId").orderBy("Timestamp")
)
```

Comment: This code will not work with structured streaming since none-time-based windows are not supported.